# Meteor MUP failed authentication using ssh ed25519

Tags: meteor, ssh-keys, meteor-up, ed25519, ssh2

**Problem**

I want to setup my config using `mup setup`. However it fails in all possible configs:

```js
{
  host: '1.2.3.4',
  username: 'root',
  pem: '/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519',
}
```

Fails, where module `ssh2` (which seems to be the part of MUP that handles [the client auth](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/blob/3c7120a75c12ea12fdd5688e33574c12e158fd07/src/plugins/default/command-handlers.js) requests) can't parse the (unkown) format of the key.

```js
{
  host: '1.2.3.4',
  username: 'root',
  password: '...'
}
```

Fails, because my server only accepts login using key authentication (`ssh -i`)

```js
{
  host: '1.2.3.4',
  username: 'root',
  // or leave blank to authenticate using ssh-agent
}
```

Fails also with `ssh2` due to unknown key format. Note, that using my ssh-agent from default OSX terminal works as expected.

**Background**

The node `ssh2` module seems to [not support ssh ed25519](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/352) and I can only login to the server using the ssh key.

**Question**

Is there any possible way to authenticate `mup setup` without using the node module ssh2 or am I locked out from using MUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the exact same problem.

The ssh2 npm module isn't as fully featured as your command line ssh. The types of keys supported are limited. I know that the ed25519 format unfortunately isn't supported. It's a little odd, because it uses ssh-agent to get the key, but doesn't support all types.

My only option (short of trying to upgrade the ssh2 module myself) was to use an RSA key.